# android tablet for designer?

Tags: android, drawing-tablet

I am kinda on a tight budget and I want to start designing stuff on a computer screen and I am looking for a cheap but decent tablet so i can start using Sketchbook pro as a start. I was looking into android tablet like Asus MeMO pad. Any advice or help would be helpful. I am not looking for a pad,just a tablet for on to go type stuff

Comment: Make sure the software you want works on the tablet, make sure the tablet is the best you can buy in the budget. Come back and ask questions if you have something more specific. Profit.

Comment: No one here could possibly know what **you** need in a tablet/mobile device. All of them will run Sketchbook pro. It's up to you to decide your budget and necessary features.

Comment: Does the Kindle HD offer SBpro? It seems to be a decent android tablet option.

Answer (score 1):

There's one relevant factor  for design other than price and personal preference: does it have a digitizer for a **pressure-sensitive pen**? And if it does, is it any good - is the pressure smooth, or does it give unexpected blobs?

I know that the **Samsung Galaxy Note** "s-pen" is good and uses the same tech as in Wacom tablet PCs (so, good, smooth pressure but could be more sensitive to soft strokes).  They come in a variety of sizes and prices.

Another advantage is,  since they're digital,  on Android 4+ there's an on-screen cursor when you hover, which is great for  precision (not sure if this is Samsung only or all Android tablets with the tech built in).

I think some other companies (HTC, Asus?) have  some tablets with similar. I think they're generally not as good - if see one you like, try the pen in a shop or look for comparison videos on YouTube.

---

Since you mention doing design on Android,  as well as Sketchbook, try **Infinite Design** and **Infinite Painter**. Great interface and Infinite Design is the closest I've found to a decent vector design app on Android. Downside is, they're buggy and crash a lot (save often), and the interface takes a little figuring out, but it's great when you do.

---

If anyone with a similar question has money to burn, the **Wacom Cintiq Companion Hybrid** is the best around - same tech as a latest-gen  Wacom Intuos or Cintiq* and you can connect it to a PC or Mac to use as a top of the range drawing screen, as well as using it on it's own with Android. But it costs a bomb.

**meaning, super sensitive including to very soft strokes, and when connected to something like Photoshop on a PC/Mac, some brushes can take into account the angle you're holding the pen*